# Do absolutely nothing

Tags: code-golf

Write a program that has at least one byte that, when run, does absolutely nothing.
I thought this would be done by now, but I can't find any other challenges like this.

How to tell if it does nothing:

- No variables are declared
- Nothing is returned
- Input does nothing
- You could run a program after it and it would run normally
- It's like you never ran it in the first place

That's it.

Comment: I'd recommend using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for future challenges.

Comment: Pretty much any C-family language, 1 byte: just a space

Comment: @Bbrk24 Not quite, many require you to define a `main()` function or similar--but in those that don't, this can be 0 bytes

Comment: So do we count "use up CPU cycles" as "nothing?" How do you qualify "run normally," and "like you never ran it?" If I run this program from the terminal, it will keep a record. What if the subsequent program "normally" depends on terminal history?

Answer (score 1):

## Polyglot, 1 byte

Just a newline. This program does nothing in many languages, including [JavaScript](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Q8EAA), [Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/4PBAA), the list goes on

Comment: The challenge says "at least one byte".

Comment: @Bbrk24, Oops, will fix